# Will the ideal gas equation change if we consider non equillibrium condition and then use kinetic approach and thermodynamic approach?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

My teacher said that in equilibrium no matter what approach we use we arrive to same result i.e. in this case ideal gas equation. So if we were to use the two approaches (thermodynamics and kinetic theory respectively) will the two approaches lead to different results

Answer (score 2):

The ideal gas equation doesn't change during non equilibrium conditions, it just doesn't apply *during* non equilibrium conditions. It only applies under equilibrium conditions.  Once equilibrium is re-established, the equation applies.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Thermodynamics is a *phenomenological* approach - the ideal gas equation is simply postulated (or derived from more elementary laws of Charles, Gay-Lussac and Boyle-Mariotte).

In statistical physics the ideal gas equation is obtained from Boltzmann distribution. Since the latter is the equilibrium solution of the kinetic equation, the same result follows from the kinetic theory.